# Can you display current time in Excel, including milliseconds, as an integer without punctuation?

Tags: excel

I want the time to read as DAYhourMINsecMILLISEC

i.e. `2015021911045615`

```
=NOW() can display 20150219110456.15
```

My end goal is to produce an unique, non-duplicated integer for document indexing.

Comment: If you're talking about the datatype `Integer`, you wont be able to as the value will be above the 32k limit. You'll need to use `Long` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick some cell and enter:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(NOW(),"yyyymmddhhmmss.000"),".","")
```

To exclude the *Year* or *Month*, just change the format.

Comment: suggested improvement: =TEXT(NOW(),"yyyymmddhhmmss.00")*100

Comment: @Porcupine911  Although the idea is nice, we loose the last digit

Comment: =TEXT(NOW(),"yyyymmddhhmmss.000")*1000

Comment: @Porcupine911  Once again your math is good!  But Excel's precision hides the very last digit.  My formula really results in a **Text** value rather than a **Number**

Comment: Yes, it does. I added my comment with the intent of ending up with a unique number in case that's what the OP wanted. Cheers!

Comment: @Porcupine911  Thank you for your comments........if we could drop, say the *Year*, then your approach would be better than mine!

Answer (score 1):

I would change the value to a string and remove the . using replace function. Or multiply the value times 100 to remove decimal values then flip to string.

Either of these should work:

=TEXT(NOW()*100,"#0")

=SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(NOW(),"#0.00"),".","")